# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; after deploying to heroku in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app running Materialize css and it works just fine in development.
Right after I deploy to heroku I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` in the application.js file.

The line of code reads: `parentNode,;null!==i&&!t(i).is(do..`and I just can't find it in my assets.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: what happens when you run `rake assets:precompile`? Let me know if you get a similar error

Comment: It runs well. I don't get any errors.

Comment: @oreoluwa It doesn't throw any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what fixed it but here's what I did.

1. Cleared my cached assets.
2. Erased avery trace of bootstrap in my app.
3. Precompiled again and pushed to heroku.

It works fine now